# JS, Mongoose, whats the difference between Type Vs. type?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

whats the difference between `Type` Vs. `type` ?!

```
available : {type: [ {Type:ProductAvailable} ]}
```

when i use type, like below:-

```
available : {type: [ {type:ProductAvailable} ]}
```

it fires errors:-

> \mongoose\lib\schema.js:616
>           throw new TypeError('Undefined type `' + name + '` at array `' + path +
>
> TypeError: Undefined type `undefined` at array `available`

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

**type**  is [schemaType](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html)  (String,Number,Date,Buffer,Boolean,Mixed,ObjectId,Array,Decimal128,Map)

**Type** : is used with mongoose schema

you can also directly use below :

```
available : {type: [ProductAvailable]}
```

meaning : available is Array of ProductAvailable